# Batch file copy similar files except a certain one

Tags: batch-file, copy, xcopy

I have code that copies certain types from one directory to another. 
Below is not the exact code but something similar since it has some personal information.

```
for /R Documents\OtherFiles\BatTest\ %%f in (
    *.aspx, *.xml, *.asax, *.asmx, *.config, *.Master
) do copy %%f Documents\OtherFiles\DestinationTest\
```

However in the folder there could be multiple config files.

```
BatTest\web.config
BatTest\web2.config
BatTest\test.config
```

How do I transfer all config files such as web.config and test.config but not include the web2.config? I understand that I can simply manually type it all in but in case there's more config files in the future, would it be possible to avoid typing it all again? Such as if there's a site1.config and prod1.config that I need to transfer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
for /R Documents\OtherFiles\BatTest\ %%f in (
 *.aspx, *.xml, *.asax, *.asmx, *.config, *.Master
) do echo %%~nxf|findstr /x /L /i /g:"myexcludefile.txt" >nul&if errorlevel 1 copy %%f Documents\OtherFiles\DestinationTest\
```

Should work for you (I'd test it first by using `echo copy...`)

`findstr` would read in the filename and extension of `%%f`, and try to find and exact (`/x`) literal (`/L`) case-insensitive (`/i`) match in the file referenced by `/g:`. If the name is found in the file, `errorlevel` will be set to 0. `if not errorlevel 0` tests errorlevel for being non-zero and executes the `copy` if the filename is **not** found in the file.

All you'd need to to is set up `myexcludefile.txt` with the excluded filenames, one to a line, like

```
web2.config
excludemetoo.config
```

Your existing batch would appear to "flatten" the source tree, producing a single directory. I suppose that's what you want.

---

Here is a working version

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=U:\documents\OtherFiles\BatTest\GOSCCMWeb"
SET "backupdir=U:\documents\OtherFiles\DestinationTest"

:: This part is simply to force the two directories to exist and put some dummy files into them

MD %targetdir% 2>nul
MD %backupdir% 2>nul
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,5) DO COPY nul "%targetdir%\file%%a.config" >NUL 2>nul
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,5) DO COPY nul "%targetdir%\web%%a.config" >NUL 2>nul

for /R "%targetdir%" %%f in (
    *.aspx, *.xml, *.asax, *.asmx, *.config, *.Master
) do echo %%~nxf|findstr /x /L /i /g:"q27990439.txt" >nul&if errorlevel 1 ECHO copy "%%f" "%backupdir%\"
GOTO :EOF
```

The exclude file `q27990439.txt` contains

```
web2.config
```

Listing of the target directory

```
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 02DD-1000

 Directory of U:\documents\OtherFiles\BatTest\GOSCCMWeb

18/01/2015  03:50    <DIR>          .
18/01/2015  03:50    <DIR>          ..
18/01/2015  03:51                 0 file1.config
18/01/2015  03:51                 0 file2.config
18/01/2015  03:51                 0 file3.config
18/01/2015  03:51                 0 file4.config
18/01/2015  03:51                 0 file5.config
18/01/2015  03:51                 0 web1.config
18/01/2015  03:51                 0 web2.config
18/01/2015  03:51                 0 web3.config
18/01/2015  03:51                 0 web4.config
18/01/2015  03:51                 0 web5.config
              10 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   2,126,544,896 bytes free
```

Result of executing this batch:

```
copy "U:\documents\OtherFiles\BatTest\GOSCCMWeb\file1.config" "U:\documents\OtherFiles\DestinationTest\"
copy "U:\documents\OtherFiles\BatTest\GOSCCMWeb\file2.config" "U:\documents\OtherFiles\DestinationTest\"
copy "U:\documents\OtherFiles\BatTest\GOSCCMWeb\file3.config" "U:\documents\OtherFiles\DestinationTest\"
copy "U:\documents\OtherFiles\BatTest\GOSCCMWeb\file4.config" "U:\documents\OtherFiles\DestinationTest\"
copy "U:\documents\OtherFiles\BatTest\GOSCCMWeb\file5.config" "U:\documents\OtherFiles\DestinationTest\"
copy "U:\documents\OtherFiles\BatTest\GOSCCMWeb\web1.config" "U:\documents\OtherFiles\DestinationTest\"
copy "U:\documents\OtherFiles\BatTest\GOSCCMWeb\web3.config" "U:\documents\OtherFiles\DestinationTest\"
copy "U:\documents\OtherFiles\BatTest\GOSCCMWeb\web4.config" "U:\documents\OtherFiles\DestinationTest\"
copy "U:\documents\OtherFiles\BatTest\GOSCCMWeb\web5.config" "U:\documents\OtherFiles\DestinationTest\"
```

Note the absence of "web2.config"

The required COPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files.

Changing `/g:` to `/g/c:` in the original should cause `findstr` to ignore the `/g` switch as `/c:...` is not a valid filename. The `/c:"whatever"` would then have established `whatever` as a string-to-match. This would not have been matched by any entry in the stream of filenames, so `errorlevel` would be set to `1` each time and the `copy` command would be generated.

The location of the file must be supplied explicitly to the `/g:` switch, but will be implicitly relative to the directory from which the command to execute the batch file is run if it is not provided as an absolute location. As such, it can be placed wherever you like - just provide the absolute path if required.

Comment: I'm getting an error that says FINDSTR: Cannot read strings from Web_Int.config. Would this be that I'm not formatting something correctly? I tried to take out the string in the file name.
Would the position of the batch files make any difference? The batch file is in the same position as the other two folders and the excluded me  file is in one folder.

    \OtherFiles\BatTest\Deploy.bat
    \OtherFiles\BatTest\Folder1
    \OtherFiles\BatTest\Folder1\ExcludeMe.config
    \OtherFiles\BatTest\Folder2

Comment: Ok so Originally i got the FINDSTR;Cannot read strings from Web_Int.config.
But after adding a /c after the /g it seemed to work now but it said that /g is ignored.
for /R Documents\OtherFiles\BatTest\GOSCCMWeb %%f in (*.aspx, *.xml, *.asax, *.asmx, *.config, *.Master) do echo %%~nxf|findstr /x /L /i /g /c:"WebInt.config" >nul&if errorlevel 1 copy %%f Documents\OtherFiles\BatTest\Folder

Can you explain why it's working now and not before? How can I fix the findstr error from before properly?